# Javascript library to create MTOM SOAP messages

Tags: javascript, soap, mtom

Can you introduce a javascript library in which we can create a SOAP request and add attachments to it as well?The library should be able to do the following:

- Create a SOAP message based on **WSDL**
- support **MTOM** file attachment

Or if it doesn't exist at all,can you give me some clues on how to implement it? Is it even possible?

Comment: Did you ever find something that supports MTOM?